# Why I get error when I attach reference to js file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I fill shame to ask this silly question but anyway I get this erorr:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Any time that I add this ref:

```
 <script src="../Scripts/ddd.js"></script>
```

to index.cshtml page.

Here is index.cshtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="../Scripts/ddd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Home      
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

And here is ddd.js file:

```
(function () {
    alert("ddd")
}());
```

**UPDATE**

I use asp.net core 2.2

Any idea why I get the error above?

Comment: Looks good to me. Can you post your generated code from browser? Maybe the server adds something weird to your code. And add `type="text/javascript"`to your script tag.

Comment: @alexP html code is the same. I try to open this way: http://localhost:55315/Scripts/ddd.js javascript file but I get the error/; This localhost page can’t be found

Comment: Maybe the missing semicolon after alert?

Comment: Should the js file be in ./Scripts/ddd.js

Comment: @nithin   ./Scripts/ddd.js  - what the point?

Comment: @Michael I mean, the location of the script relative  to the index html matters. If I add the JS code directly in the HTML, it works. So in this case, the only possibility is that your script file is not accessible. Some asp.net experts might be able to help.

Comment: Make sure you aren't using any bundling (in your master/layout file), or that might get you into trouble.

Comment: I found my mistake in .net core I have to put js files inside wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 0):

please add  reference like this

```
<script src="~/Scripts/ddd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core default root folder is always wwwroot folder. So you need to put your files under wwwroot folder. If you want to refer that file from a regular html file you can use '''
"../Scripts/ddd.js"
'''

However if you refer it in a cshtml page with razor code then you would need
'''
"~/Scripts/ddd.js"
'''

"~" points to root folder in razor syntax.